# numpy.subtract performs subtraction wrong on 1-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

> I read the post [is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and get Why it
> happens, but I couldn't find a solution that could help me..
>
> How can I do the correct subtraction?

Python version 2.6.6, Numpy version 1.4.1.

I have two numpy.ndarray each one contain float32 values, origin and new. I'm trying to use numpy.subtract to subtract them but I get the following (odd) result:

```
>>> import numpy as 
>>> with open('base_R.l_BSREM_S.9.1_001.bin', 'r+') as fid:
        origin = np.fromfile(fid, np.float32)
>>> with open('new_R.l_BSREM_S.9.1_001.bin', 'r+') as fid:
        new = np.fromfile(fid, np.float32)
>>> diff = np.subtract(origin, new)
>>> origin[5184939]
0.10000000149011611938
>>> new[5184939]
0.00000000023283064365
>>> diff[5184939]
0.10000000149011611938
```

Also when I try to subtract the arrays at 5184939 I get the same result as diff[5184939]

```
>>> origin[5184939] - new[5184939]
0.10000000149011611938
```

But when I do the following I get this results:

```
>>> 0.10000000149011611938 - 0.00000000023283064365
0.10000000125728548
```

and that's not equal to diff[5184939]

How the right subtraction can be done? (0.10000000125728548 is the one that I need)

Please help, and Thanks in advance

Comment: The proposed duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken may explain why you can differing floating representations, but does not explain the difference in this case.  Unduplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You might add your Python and numpy versions to the question.

Differences can arise from `np.float32` v `np.float64` dtype, the default Python float type, as well as display standards.  `numpy` uses different display rounding than the underlying Python.

The subtraction itself does not differ.

I can reproduce the `0.10000000125728548` value, which may also display as `0.1` (out 8 decimals).

I'm not sure where the `0.10000000149011611938` comes from.  That looks as though `new[5184939]` was identically 0, not just something small like `0.00000000023283064365`.